# Elapsed time measurement issue - JAVA

Tags: java, android, time

I'm building a simple game on Android and I want to check the execution duration of some functions.

To do so I wrote a class (`TimeLog`) which saves the `System.nanotime()` on a Double field when instantiated. The class of course has an `end()` method which subtracts the time it got when instantiated to the current `System.nanotime()`.

The problem is that if I try to measure the duration of a method which contains other methods sometimes inner methods take more time to execute than the method which contains them. I don't understand where I'm wrong.

---

**Here's an example:**

```
void myFunc(){
  TimeLog out = new TimeLog();
  inner1();
  inner2();
  out.end();
}

void inner1(){
  TimeLog in1 = new TimeLog();
  //something...
  in1.end();
}

void inner2(){
  TimeLog in2 = new TimeLog();
  //something...
  in2.end();
}


Main(){
  myFunc();
}
```

Sometimes in1 or in2 return higher values than out.

**Here's TimeLog:**

```
public class Timelog
{

  private double startTime;
  private double duration;

  public TimeLog (){
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
  }

  public void end(){
    duration = (int)(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
  }

  public void log(){
    Log.d("TIMELOG", ":" + duration);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... why would you ever cast a long value to an int, then into a double!? Maybe that's where the problem comes from...

Comment: @JayC667 I though that System.nanotime() returns an integer value. I mean, if it returns nanoseconds than they are very large integer numbers and not floating points.

Comment: Those "very large integer numbers" are basically a `long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `System.nanoTime()` returns a `long`, not an `int` or a `double` so you should use `long` to do proper calculation. Im not sure if that fixes your problem, please post a sample output if not.

Edit: Could you show the part where you call the `log()` methods too? It is not called anywhere in that code.

Comment: Thank you, I modified my code (long instead of double) and now it returns "better" results. It was a stupid error but I couldn't spot it.